# Can't use my HDD drive for storage (Please Help)

Tags: 20.04, hard-drive

I recently switched to Ubuntu because Windows 10 is dogwater and I need help for my HDD drive to work, by that I mean I can't install anything using my HDD.

It will only give me the option to install through SSD. And my windows drive has the windows folders on it which I deleted.

But then I realized that I had a "Windows Network" which is making me think that I've dual booted and not have fully committed to Ubuntu which I remember in the installation process that I have selected the option to get rid of Windows, so I don't know if I've dual booted or have committed to Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: First you asked 2 separate questions one about Steam and a second about WoW. Only 1 question per question please. All the drama in no way is going to get any one to help you. For the WoW issue you have of course checked the wine formus to see if it is supported? https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1081

Comment: Ok i changed it

Comment: Exactly the same disk arrangement as mine - and I don't have any windoze incidence on my pc. The drive called "main storage" is where you can copy other files to (such as videos, music, documents etc) but there is plenty of space for installing most of what you will need on the main "Computer" volume so no need to panic. You can see where "main storage" is mounted by running `Disks` Please identify which verson of ubuntu you are using.

Comment: I want to use my main storage for games tho, you know how big games are these days. 20.04 LTS

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP can't decide which question to ask and the purpose of the question is completely unclear.